# How does Mocha handle imports?

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js

I'm writing some test scripts and noticed that when I import  a specific module and execute a specific function within that module, Mocha runs the entire module plus the one I have specified.

In test.js

```
const myModule = require('../someModule');

describe('Test',function(){
  it('Should run a function in mu module',funciton(){
     myModule.someFunction(test);  
  };
}
```

In myModule.js

```
module.exports = { someFunction };

function someFunction(someInput){
  return true;
}
```

Now say I include a console log within my module as shown below:

```
module.exports = { someFunction };

console.log('Loging inside the module');


function someFunction(someInput){
  return true;
}
```

When I run my Mocha test it will run my funciton but will also run my `console.log`

Can someone please explain this?

Comment: I believe that's a general behaviour of javascript files, Javascript engine will parse and execute lines of module being imported.. If you're wanting to not run certain logic until specifically called, you may wanted to wrap that in a function

Comment: Could you elaborate on the Javascript engine part @Varinder

Comment: Mocha does not have a specific way to handle modules. Mocha loads modules like regular code

Comment: Here is a great explanation to how "require" works and I think it answers your question and more. http://fredkschott.com/post/2014/06/require-and-the-module-system/

Comment: Well in that case not why and how does Node/JS handle it